# Calculating distance using Job System

Tags: unity, multithreading

I am trying to find out the distance between game objects and the player position using Job System, But I am getting an error of unsafe pointer race condition. Can anyone tell me how to access transform in job system? to measure distance.
 Following is the code.

```
struct PositionUpdateJob : IJobParallelForTransform

{

    public TransformAccessArray Object;

    public float DIst;


    public void Execute(int i, TransformAccess transform)

    {

         DIst = (transform.position- Object[0].position ).sqrMagnitude;
        if (DIst < 20)
        {
           // Do Something
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Main script which measures gameObject position against its children

```
public Transform Player;
public List<Transform> ChildList = new List<Transform>();    
public TransformAccessArray Transformz;
public float Dist;
PositionUpdateJob m_Job;
JobHandle m_PositionJobHandle;  
public TransformAccessArray Mey;
void Start ()
{
    Transformz = new TransformAccessArray(0, -1);
    Mey = new TransformAccessArray(0,-1);
    Mey.Add(transform);
    GetChildRecursive(gameObject);
    }
private void GetChildRecursive(GameObject obj)
{
 //To Get All childrens for transform access array
}
void Update()
{
    m_PositionJobHandle.Complete();
    m_Job = new PositionUpdateJob()
    {
        DIst = Dist,
        Object = Mey
};
    m_Job.Schedule(Transformz);
  }
private void LateUpdate()
{
    m_PositionJobHandle.Complete();
    Transformz.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered working on an array of positions, instead of an array of transforms?

Answer (score 1):

So after getting some help from the unity forum I fixed the problem. I am posting code below hope it will help someone:)

```
struct PositionUpdateJob : IJobParallelForTransform

{
    public NativeArray<float> _distances;
    public Vector3 _playerPosition;

    public void Execute(int i, TransformAccess transform)
    {
        _distances[i] = Vector3.Distance(_playerPosition, transform.position);
    }
}


PositionUpdateJob job = new TransformDistanceCheckJob()
    {
        _distances = distances,
        _playerPosition = Player.position,
    };
    JobHandle jobHandle = job.Schedule(Transformz);
    jobHandle.Complete();
    for (int i = 0; i < distances.Length; i++)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("distance for for index " + i + ": " + distances [i]);
    }
```

Ps: Performance is great on 5000 children with burst compiler it takes around 2ms where without job system it was 8ms.